# mysql query get range between date not from table

Tags: mysql

I have payment table info like this

```
ID Costumer | start_pay  | Payment
1           | 2014-01-01 | 1.500
2           | 2013-12-01 | 900
```

that information they must pay every month, i want calculating it for range between start_pay to `CURDATE`

if `CURDATE` is `2014-03-01` (Y-m-d) the result I want like this

```
ID Costumer | start_pay  | Payment | total_to_pay | month_count 
1           | 2014-01-01 | 1.500   | 4.500        | 3
2           | 2013-12-01 | 900     | 3.600        | 4
```

can i do that with mysql query?

Comment: How is month count 3? It is still February

Comment: that why i say it "if CURDATE", in indonesia today is 1st march, middle of the night :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_SUB(start_pay,INTERVAL 1 MONTH), CURDATE()) AS 
month_count,Payment * month_count AS total_to_pay FROM TABLE
```

Note that if the difference is less than a month it will output 0

Comment: in start_pay row '2013-12-01' the month_count is 3. how i add one month, or decrease one month from start_pay, to make the result is 4 (dec 13,jan 14, feb 14 and mar 14)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is you can add 1 to the statement `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, start_pay, CURDATE())+1`
 but I'm not sure what the issue is with the statement above

Comment: i was fixed your query, may be like this SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_SUB(start_pay,INTERVAL 1 MONTH), CURDATE()) AS month_count FROM TABLE so the result be like i want it. thanks one problem is solved (mount_count), remains "total_to_pay" need to answer

Comment: just add `payment*month_count AS total_pay` in your select clause

Comment: solved : SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_SUB(start_pay,INTERVAL 1 MONTH), CURDATE()) AS month_count,(SELECT Payment * month_count) AS total_to_pay FROM TABLE

Comment: can you edit your answer like my answer, if somebody have same problem so they can solved. or i create one

Answer (score 0):

[PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff) is basically made for this type of calculation:

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(start_pay, '%Y%m')) from your table;
```